# Debugging reversed Android Application without emulator for Dynamic Analysis

Tags: android, analysis, apktool, androguard

Suppose I download an android real-world app from `Google Play` and planned to do a dynamic analysis in the android application that received. thus, I first did the reverse engineering with `apktool` on the received android applications, and then by adding `build.xml` file and a few other files, executed the `sudo ant clean debug` command.
This can be done on several projects with ant structures that have been built by my own. But Unfortunately, it does not happen for real-world applications and gives the following error which is related to the resources.

```
Buildfile: /home/xxx/APK/Accept/psiphon3/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 25.2.5
 [checkenv] Installed at /usr/local/Application/Android

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: psiphone3
  [gettype] Project Type: Application

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 19.1.0
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for psiphone3...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.4.2
[gettarget] API level:        19
[gettarget] WARNING: No minSdkVersion value set. Application will install on all Android versions.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/xxx/APK/Accept/psiphon3/libs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/xxx/APK/Accept/psiphon3/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/xxx/APK/Accept/psiphon3/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/xxx/APK/Accept/psiphon3/bin/rsObj
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/xxx/APK/Accept/psiphon3/bin/rsLibs
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/xxx/APK/Accept/psiphon3/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/xxx/APK/Accept/psiphon3/bin/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/xxx/APK/Accept/psiphon3/bin/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for psiphone3...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [aapt] invalid resource directory name: /home/xxx/APK/Accept/psiphon3/res/values-b+sr+Latn

BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/Application/Android/tools/ant/build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/Application/Android/tools/ant/build.xml:694: null returned: 1
```

Is there a way to do debugging without the execution of programs on the real-world emulator or device?

Comment: Not sure its possible, how else is the code executed without being run on an emulator or device? And what is the reason for not wanting to debug on on a emulator or device?

Comment: By default, there are two build types available for every Android app: one for debugging your app—the debug build—and one for releasing your app to users—the release build. My goal is one.